# how to save values/data in java even if you close it

Tags: java, save

I'm making a game where you can get coins, highscore etc. and keep them without setting it back to default when I exit and close the game. May I know how to do this?

Comment: You can save your stuff in databases or in files for example. See this [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955396/whats-the-easiest-way-to-persist-java-objects).

Comment: Use a file or store the values in Database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the state to be restored even after your program exists and runs again, below are the options-

1. Store the data in DB
2. Serialize in the file system
3. Store the data on disk

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JDBC to store data to database in java.